# Scrambled JSON string

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to build a JSON string using json python module.

In particular I want this structure:

```
data = {
    'Id' : deviceId,
    'UnixTime' : unixTime,
    'Temp' : round( temperature, 2 ),
    'Rh' : round( humidity,2 ),
}
```

But when I execute: `jsonString = json.dumps( data )`

All field are scrambled.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: That's because there is **no order in a dictionary**...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Python dict and JSON object are unordered collections.

Use the sort_keys parameter, to sort the keys:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
'{"b": 2, "a": 1}'
>>> json.dumps({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, sort_keys=True)
'{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
```

If you need a particular order; you could use collections.OrderedDict:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> json.dumps(OrderedDict([("a", 1), ("b", 2)]))
'{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
>>> json.dumps(OrderedDict([("b", 2), ("a", 1)]))
'{"b": 2, "a": 1}'
```